# PHP loop through data from JSON string

Tags: php, json, foreach

I want to get **ItemCategory->id's** for each **Item->id**

How can I do it in the best way?

Here is a part of JSON data item

```
"6": {
    "Item": {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "test",
      "description": "description",
    },
    "ItemThumbnail": null,
    "ItemCategory": {
      "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "name",
        "status": "active",
        "date_created": "2015-07-07 11:23:52",
        "date_updated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      },
      "4": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name",
        "status": "active",
        "date_created": "2015-07-07 11:23:52",
        "date_updated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      }
    },
    "ItemGroup": []
},
```

Comment: So you would like to get `id : 3` from 6? Just post your desired output and your entire json? It's hard to give you the right answer with this incomplete json.

Comment: it's a one item of response->data from json string

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your json string to a PHP array using `$array = json_decode($str, true);`, then loop your array and extract the information you need.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for more detail on json_decode

Answer (score 1):

After json decode use this.

foreach($Item as $Items)

{

```
$ItemCategory = $Items->ItemCategory;

foreach($ItemCategory as $ItemCategorys)

{

    echo $ItemCategorys->id;

    }

}
```